# Check if the running code is unit test case or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, uialertview

I want to check if the running code is unit tese case or not execute different code for the result such as:

```
    if ( unit test case is running )
{
do something
}
else
{
do other thing
}
```

any idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad approach you should try to simulate logic parts which you are trying to avoid by this statemetn through Mock ojects or other mechanism.

Now to your question you can use a oolean variable like `isUnittest` which you set on test setup and Teardown, ut as saied i dont recommend you doing this.

Comment: thanks for the clue but the thing is i want to pop an alert only if unit test case is running and i dont want to add any bool variable in the source code. I just want to know which target running  is there any way to check it?

Comment: doesnt the framework you use for unittest provide such a flag?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me (iOS 8, Xcode 6):

```
- (BOOL) isRunningTest {
    return NSClassFromString(@"XCTestCase") != nil;
}
```

I think this is cleaner and easier than other answers.

Comment: This might be a good idea only if you write all your test cases in one class name XCTestCase.. However I realised that the thing I was going to achieve was a very bad idea!! Thanks for your effort...

Comment: Indeed `XCTestCase` is part of the iOS Test framework so it would work anyway (at least, if you are not importing the framework in the app, which doesn't make too much sense).

Comment: As a side note, casting an object to `BOOL` can yield `NO` even when the object isn't `nil`. The `BOOL` will use the last few bits the pointer, which can be something like this: `00000000`, which will register as `NO`. See "Casting to `BOOL`" in this article: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-12-14-objective-c-pitfalls.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't message `UIAlertView` directly. Instead, use dependency injection, for example, a property like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Class alertViewClass;
```

Then your code to create an alert can do

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[_alertViewClass alloc] initWithTitle:…etc…];
```

In your test code, inject a different class. I use https://github.com/jonreid/JMRTestTools to specify `JMRMockAlertView`. I can then test the alert calls with `JMRMockAlertViewVerifier`. (In fact, this enables test-driven development of alerts.)

Edit: These days, I use https://github.com/jonreid/ViewControllerPresentationSpy

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to let the class have customizable behavior controlled via a static method, and have test case call that method in its static load method.

I had a similar issue using storyboard and an external restful service for authentication via oauth.  The app delegate would check if there is a valid oauth token in appdelegate:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and if not, then programatically trigger segue to do the oauth login.  But this was not desirable in test cases.  To solve this, I created a static method within the app delegate to disable the login screen.  This is the code within my app delegate:

```
static Boolean showLoginScreen = TRUE ;

+ (void) disableLoginScreen
{
    showLoginScreen = FALSE ;
    NSLog(@"disabled login screen") ;
}
```

The test case had its load method to do the following:

```
// disable login screen for the test case
+ (void) load {
    NSLog( @"now disabling login screen" ) ;
   [XYZAppDelegate disableLoginScreen];
}
```

This worked because the test case class was loaded before application was initialized.  Of course you must check the value of this flag within app delegate to trigger/not trigger the login segue.  Other alternatives I tried but rejected were as follows:

- Create a preprocessor define on the test target.  But the compiler only compiles the test case files with this flag, not the application source.  See http://www.innovaptor.com/blog/2013/09/02/xcode-preprocessor-macros-for-test-code.html
- Use the static initialize method of the test case to call the disable method.  On test case run, the application is started before the test case class is loaded.  See http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/06/iniailize-can-be-executed-multiple-times-load-not-so-much/ for some details.