# Unit test is incorrectly executing code from the launch view controller

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I have a simple struct as below which is part of an iOS Application:

```
struct Country: JSONObject {
    let name: String!
    let code: String!

    static let nameKey = "name"
    static let codeKey = "dial_code"

    init?(_ json: [String: AnyObject]) throws {
        guard let name = json[Country.nameKey] as? String else {
           throw JSONError.InvalidTypeForKey(key: Country.nameKey)
        }

        guard let code = json[Country.codeKey] as? String else {
            throw JSONError.InvalidTypeForKey(key: Country.codeKey)
        }

        self.name = name
        self.code = code
    }
}
```

I wrote a unit test to test initialisation of this class:

```
func testCorrectInitialisationOfCountry() {
    let countryDict = [Country.nameKey: "England", Country.codeKey: "+44"]

    do {
        let country = try Country(countryDict)!
        XCTAssert(countryDict[Country.nameKey] == country.name, "The country name does not match")
        XCTAssert(countryDict[Country.codeKey] == country.code, "The country code does not match")
    }
    catch _ {
        print("Initialisation of country failed with an exception")
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is this struct is initialised several times in the viewDidLoad() method in the first view controller of my app.

For some reason, that viewDidLoad() method is being called when I run my tests and generating incorrect code coverage because of that. The picture below shows the unit test stats generated by Xcode.

[image]

The numbers "241" should actually be just "1". The other 240 times, that line is being executed from the launch view controller which is not under test.

How can I stop the view controller code from executing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit tests are run inside of the context of your running app.

I think your best bet is to write your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to not bring up the view controller if started by a test (or bring up a simpler one)

This answer offers one way to check if your app is running in a unit test:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30306450/3937

To stop the automatic loading of the first storyboard, remove it as the launch storyboard and code the loading yourself following this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702730/3937

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However I am using storyboards, and my launch storyboard is set in my xcodeproj file. I am not aware of a way to stop the VC from loading in the AppDelegate if you are using storyboards. Could you please share a code snippet if that can be done?

Comment: Thanks!! The second code snippet to launch the storyboard in code doesn't quite work, but just needs the following line added before it:

self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [setUp](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496262-setup) method (inside your unit test class) which is invoked **AFTER** the `viewDidLoad`.

> Override this method to customize the initial state for all tests in the test case.

This way, you can reset whatever you need just before your test methods execute.

For example, I needed to reset a singleton that was invoked via a view controller. Note that you can reset between each method via the [tearDown](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctest/1500463-teardown) method:

> called once after each test completes. Override this method to perform any per-test cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for your problem. You can short circuit your app launch as described in link below.

[How To: Unit Test Without Running The Entire App](http://fullytyped.com/2019/01/06/unit-test-without-entire-app/)